# How to modify the name of a foreign key in a table, such as the foreign key name below, want to change to'one'

Tags: mysql, sql

How to modify the name of a foreign key in a table, such as the foreign key name is article_ibfk_1, want to change to'one'.

```
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| CONSTRAINT_CATALOG | CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | CONSTRAINT_NAME | TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | ORDINAL_POSITION | POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT | REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA | REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME | REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME |
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| def                | test              | PRIMARY         | def           | test         | article    | id          |                1 |                          NULL | NULL                    | NULL                  | NULL                   |
| def                | test              | article_ibfk_1  | def           | test         | article    | tag         |                1 |                             1 | test                    | tag                   | id                     |
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You drop it, and then you create it again with the new name:

```
alter table article drop foreign key article_ibfk_1;

alter table article add constraint one foreign key (tag)
  references tag (id);
```

Answer (score -1):

sp_rename 'article_ibfk_1','one'

OR

EXEC sp_rename @objname = N'article_ibfk_1', @newname = N'one';

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server